# WPF: Customized control focus management

Tags: focus, wpf-controls

I was tying to set focus on a TextBox used to build a customized "Numeric Up Down" control.
This is the custom "Numeric Up Down"

```
<Style x:Key="SpinButton" TargetType="Slider" >
    <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Slider">
    <Border Grid.RowSpan="3" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="WhiteSmoke">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height=".5*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height=".5*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Name="textBoxNumericUpDown" Grid.RowSpan="3" Margin="2,0,0,0"         Text="{Binding Value,Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource     TemplatedParent}}" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="    {x:Null}" Foreground="White" BorderThickness="0" CaretBrush="White"     IsTabStop="True"/>
        <RepeatButton Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,-5,0"     Command="Slider.IncreaseLarge" Style="{StaticResource TimeRepeatButtonStyle}" Content="+" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="White" Foreground="White"     FontSize="18" Cursor="Hand" Width="44" Height="44" IsTabStop="False"/>
        <RepeatButton Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Command="Slider.DecreaseLarge"     Margin="0,1,-5,0" Style="{StaticResource TimeRepeatButtonStyle}" Content="-"     Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="White" Foreground="White" FontSize="18"     Cursor="Hand" Width="44" Height="44" IsTabStop="False"/>
    </Grid>
    </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Usage

```
<Slider PreviewTextInput="textBoxTimeMinute_PreviewTextInput" Name="textBoxTimeMinute" Width="100" Style="{StaticResource SpinButton}" Maximum="999" Margin="8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Minimum="0" IsTabStop="True" TabIndex="0"/>
<Label Grid.Column="1" Content=":" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsTabStop="False"/>
<Slider PreviewTextInput="textBoxTimeSecond_PreviewTextInput" Grid.Column="2" Name="textBoxTimeSecond" Width="100" Style="{StaticResource SpinButton}" Maximum="60" Margin="8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Minimum="-1" IsTabStop="True" TabIndex="1"/>
```

[Wanted result (Automatic focus on the first textbox if no number inside)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXMbg.png)

[Wanted result (Automatic focus on the first textbox if number inside, number is selected)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvZB3.png)

I tried different ways to make it select the correct Control, but it always selects the outer layer. In my case The Grid/Border.
Only after I press TAB I can have it select the correct TextBox Control.

Is there any way in WPF I can achieve the focus on textbox without pressing TAB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

If you want to focus a TextBox inside a ControlTemplate you have to set up a trigger on the "**IsFocused**" property.
When it becomes true then you have to set the **FocusManager.FocusedElement** field  to the name of the TextBox (or other control) you want to focus.

Below is the code I used to achieve this:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Slider">
 <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxToFocus"/> //The textbox(or any other element) I want to set focus to. It is very important to have it named, otherwise I won't know which control to focus.
 <ControlTemplate.Triggers> //The trigger
      <Trigger Property = "IsFocused" Value = "True" /> //The property the trigger is watching
           <Setter TargetName="TextBoxToFocus" Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=NumericUpDown}"/> //Setter when the trigger executes
      </Trigger>
 </ControlTelmplate.Triggers>
```